# When I run the Join function on two vector layers the distance field keeps returning "-1"

Tags: distance, attribute-joins

When joining two point layers by geographic location with the "Each point will be given attribute" selection, I keep getting a NEARDIST of -1.

Answer (score 0):

It seems one of my point layers was no longer pointing to the correct source data - I had updated the underlying shapefile, and had to reconnect the point layer to it. This fixes the -1 return!